# Removing side captions from list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

How can I remove a side caption from a list of figures? I have been trying to use the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{SCfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{blank.jpg}
\caption*{Caption}
\end{SCfigure}
\end{document}
```

However, including an `*` within `\caption*{Caption}` does not seem to work. Rather, in the list of figures, it simply replaces the word 'Caption' with an asterix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\caption*` is provided by `caption` package. Add

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

to make it work.

Comment: Thank you Leo for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it does not work for me. The LaTeX Error:\ContinuedFloat outside float appears, pointing to the offending line: \caption*{Caption}. Would you please confirm that your suggestion worked for you.

Comment: @BrigalowDad: First of all, the version of your caption package is outdated. For a perfect cooperation with the sidecap package one need v3.1 or newer of the caption package. (`\caption*` will not work inside sideway captions when using version 3.0 of the caption package. Instead one will get the error message above.) Second, if you don't want a labeled caption, why do you use the sidecap package and `\caption*` at all? You could simply place your description beside the picture, without the need of both.

Comment: @Axel: 1) Excellent. Thanks very much. Am now trying to install your latest caption package on my Mac. 2) Agree, but, for coding uniformity, prefer current approach because most of the pictures will be in ToF.